How to turn this table into a longtable
I have the following really long table, so I'd like to split it across multiple pages
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{The various mathematical parameters and variables associated with the device.}
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Tank geometry}}\\
        \midrule
        \(L_x\)    & Tank width \\
        \(L_y\)    & Tank length \\
        \(L_c\)    & Contraction length \\
        \(l_y(x)\) & Contraction wall position \\
        \(\theta\) & Contraction angle \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Hydrodynamics}}\\
        \midrule
        \(\textbf{u}(x,y,z,t)\)        & Water velocity \\
        \(\rho_0,\rho(x,y,z,t)\)       & Water density \\
        \(R(t)\)                       & Wavemaker position \\
        \(h(x,y,t)\)                   & Free-surface height \\
        \(H_0\)                        & Free-surface rest height \\
        \(\eta(x,y,t)\)                & Free-surface displacement (from rest) \\
        \(g\)                          & Gravitational acceleration \\
        \(\mathcal{P}(x,y,z,t)\)       & Constant density constraint multiplier \\
        \(\boldsymbol{\chi}(x,y,z,t)\) & Wavemaker no-slip BC constraint multiplier \\
        \(\xi(x,y,z,t)\)               & Wall no-slip BC constraint multiplier \\
        \(\psi(x,y,z,t)\)              & Free-surface kinematic BC constraint multiplier \\
        \(\phi(x,y,z,t)\)              & Conservation of mass constraint multiplier \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Buoy}}\\
        \midrule
        \(M\)              & Buoy (plus mast and magnet) mass \\
        \(Z(t)\)           & Buoy position \\
        \(Z_0\)            & Buoy rest position \\
        \(W(t)\)           & Buoy velocity \\
        \(\alpha\)         & Hull angle \\
        \(h_b(y,t)\)       & Hull position \\
        \(y_b(x,t)\)       & Waterline position \\
        \(L_b\)            & Waterline rest position \\
        \(\Theta\)         & Heaviside step function \\
        \(\lambda(x,y,t)\) & Buoy-water interface constraint multiplier \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{PTO system}}\\
        \midrule
        \(L_m\)      & Magnet length \\
        \(H_m\)      & Magnet height (above buoy) \\
        \(A_m\)      & Magnet radius \\
        \(m\)        & Magnetic moment \\
        \(D\)        & Wire diameter \\
        \(\sigma\)   & Wire conductivity \\
        \(L\)        & Coil length \\
        \(a\)        & Coil radius \\
        \(n_c\)      & Coil loop number \\
        \(L_i\)      & Coil self-inductance \\
        \(K\)        & Short-coil factor \\
        \(\alpha_h\) & Offset parameter \\
        \(R_c\)      & Coil resistance \\
        \(R_i\)      & Circuit resistance \\
        \(I(t)\)     & Current \\
        \(Q(t)\)     & Charge \\
        \(P(t)\)     & Power \\
        \(\gamma\)   & Electromagnet scale parameter \\
        \(G(Z)\)     & Magnetic field application function \\
        \(\mu_0\)    & Permeability of free space \\
        \(C\)        & Capacitor capacitance \\
        \(n_q\)      & LED quality factor \\
        \(V_T\)      & LED thermal voltage \\
        \(I_{sat}\)  & LED saturation current \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:notation}
\end{table}

I tried using the longtable environment but it causes my compilier to time-out. I've removed the table environment and turned the tabular environment into longtable - what am I doing wrong?
\begin{longtable}{cl}
    \caption{The various mathematical parameters and variables associated with the device.}
    \label{tab:notation}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Tank geometry}}\\
    \midrule
    \(L_x\)    & Tank width \\
    \(L_y\)    & Tank length \\
    \(L_c\)    & Contraction length \\
    \(l_y(x)\) & Contraction wall position \\
    \(\theta\) & Contraction angle \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Hydrodynamics}}\\
    \midrule
    \(\textbf{u}(x,y,z,t)\)        & Water velocity \\
    \(\rho_0,\rho(x,y,z,t)\)       & Water density \\
    \(R(t)\)                       & Wavemaker position \\
    \(h(x,y,t)\)                   & Free-surface height \\
    \(H_0\)                        & Free-surface rest height \\
    \(\eta(x,y,t)\)                & Free-surface displacement (from rest) \\
    \(g\)                          & Gravitational acceleration \\
    \(\mathcal{P}(x,y,z,t)\)       & Constant density constraint multiplier \\
    \(\boldsymbol{\chi}(x,y,z,t)\) & Wavemaker no-slip BC constraint multiplier \\
    \(\xi(x,y,z,t)\)               & Wall no-slip BC constraint multiplier \\
    \(\psi(x,y,z,t)\)              & Free-surface kinematic BC constraint multiplier \\
    \(\phi(x,y,z,t)\)              & Conservation of mass constraint multiplier \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Buoy}}\\
    \midrule
    \(M\)              & Buoy (plus mast and magnet) mass \\
    \(Z(t)\)           & Buoy position \\
    \(Z_0\)            & Buoy rest position \\
    \(W(t)\)           & Buoy velocity \\
    \(\alpha\)         & Hull angle \\
    \(h_b(y,t)\)       & Hull position \\
    \(y_b(x,t)\)       & Waterline position \\
    \(L_b\)            & Waterline rest position \\
    \(\Theta\)         & Heaviside step function \\
    \(\lambda(x,y,t)\) & Buoy-water interface constraint multiplier \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{PTO system}}\\
    \midrule
    \(L_m\)      & Magnet length \\
    \(H_m\)      & Magnet height (above buoy) \\
    \(A_m\)      & Magnet radius \\
    \(m\)        & Magnetic moment \\
    \(D\)        & Wire diameter \\
    \(\sigma\)   & Wire conductivity \\
    \(L\)        & Coil length \\
    \(a\)        & Coil radius \\
    \(n_c\)      & Coil loop number \\
    \(L_i\)      & Coil self-inductance \\
    \(K\)        & Short-coil factor \\
    \(\alpha_h\) & Offset parameter \\
    \(R_c\)      & Coil resistance \\
    \(R_i\)      & Circuit resistance \\
    \(I(t)\)     & Current \\
    \(Q(t)\)     & Charge \\
    \(P(t)\)     & Power \\
    \(\gamma\)   & Electromagnet scale parameter \\
    \(G(Z)\)     & Magnetic field application function \\
    \(\mu_0\)    & Permeability of free space \\
    \(C\)        & Capacitor capacitance \\
    \(n_q\)      & LED quality factor \\
    \(V_T\)      & LED thermal voltage \\
    \(I_{sat}\)  & LED saturation current \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}


Without minimal working example to reproduce your problem and test my suggestion, I can only guess: There is a \\ missing after \label{tab:notation}. So, please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Something like this?
Some comments: (a) You were missing a \\ ("double backslash") directive after the caption. (b) I would get rid of all 51 instances of \( and \) and, in their place, make the first column be in math mode automatically. (c) Don't use \textbf in math mode unless you have a very good reason for doing so; instead, use \mathbf. (d) I see no need for italic mode for the four intermediate headers.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,array,longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} >{$}c<{$} l @{}} % first column: automatic math mode

%% headers and footers

\caption{The various mathematical parameters and variables associated with the device.}
\label{tab:notation}\\
\toprule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of table

\multicolumn{2}{c}{Tank geometry}\\
\midrule
L_x    & Tank width \\
L_y    & Tank length \\
L_c    & Contraction length \\
l_y(x) & Contraction wall position \\
\theta & Contraction angle \\

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Hydrodynamics}\\
\midrule

\mathbf{u}(x,y,z,t)   & Water velocity \\
\rho_0,\rho(x,y,z,t)  & Water density \\
R(t)       & Wavemaker position \\
h(x,y,t)   & Free-surface height \\
H_0        & Free-surface rest height \\
\eta(x,y,t)& Free-surface displacement (from rest) \\
g          & Gravitational acceleration \\
\mathcal{P}(x,y,z,t)  & Constant density constraint multiplier \\
\boldsymbol{\chi}(x,y,z,t) & Wavemaker no-slip BC constraint multiplier \\
\xi(x,y,z,t)     & Wall no-slip BC constraint multiplier \\
\psi(x,y,z,t)    & Free-surface kinematic BC constraint multiplier \\
\phi(x,y,z,t)    & Conservation of mass constraint multiplier \\

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Buoy}\\
\midrule

M           & Buoy (plus mast and magnet) mass \\
Z(t)        & Buoy position \\
Z_0         & Buoy rest position \\
W(t)        & Buoy velocity \\
\alpha      & Hull angle \\
h_b(y,t)    & Hull position \\
y_b(x,t)    & Waterline position \\
L_b         & Waterline rest position \\
\Theta      & Heaviside step function \\
\lambda(x,y,t) & Buoy-water interface constraint multiplier \\

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{PTO system}\\
\midrule

L_m      & Magnet length \\
H_m      & Magnet height (above buoy) \\
A_m      & Magnet radius \\
m        & Magnetic moment \\
D        & Wire diameter \\
\sigma   & Wire conductivity \\
L        & Coil length \\
a        & Coil radius \\
n_c      & Coil loop number \\
L_i      & Coil self-inductance \\
K        & Short-coil factor \\
\alpha_h & Offset parameter \\
R_c      & Coil resistance \\
R_i      & Circuit resistance \\
I(t)     & Current \\
Q(t)     & Charge \\
P(t)     & Power \\
\gamma   & Electromagnet scale parameter \\
G(Z)     & Magnetic field application function \\
\mu_0    & Permeability of free space \\
C        & Capacitor capacitance \\
n_q      & LED quality factor \\
V_T      & LED thermal voltage \\
I_{\mathrm{sat}} & LED saturation current \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}

